# How to get all SVG elements on canvas using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to get all elements on canvas including SVGelements in fabricJS and I have tried this,

```
canvas.getObjects();
```

but this returns all objects other than SVG element I have searched all the questions regarding fabricjs but none of it helps.
Basically I want to clear the canvas but when I use this,

```
canvas.remove(...canvas.getObjects());
```

it removes all the objects, groups everything except SVG elements. It means " canvas.getObjects()" is not detecting the SVG elemenst on the canvas.

Comment: try `canvas.toSVG()`

Comment: and what would it do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/jQ3ZZ/

Comment: i want all the objects and svg too to remove all of them

Comment: when i use  canvas.remove(...this.canvas.getObjects()); it removes all the objects but svg

Comment: canvas.toSVG() is a different thing

Comment: it means that i not understood the question

Comment: i want to get all the elements on the canvas including SVG elements

Comment: but when I use canvas.getObjects();  it gives me all the objects but not the svg elements